# iPhone field test instructions

Tags: iphone, ios

> "Access the iPhone’s Field Test mode by typing `3001#12345#` in the phone’s keypad and press dial. This will bring up the Field Test menu."

Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

The correct code is

```
*3001#12345#*
```

(note the asterisks at the beginning and end).